# Translate a nested Paragraph programmatically

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

i have translated nodes with a paragraph field (content already exists, all entities are translatable). I've added a *nested paragraph field* on the *first paragraph field*. My goal is to programmatically add translated *nested paragraphs*.

```
node (
 * first paragraph field
   ** nested paragraph field
```

But when i run my update, the paragraphs on the translated nodes are still in the original language (not translated). What am i doing wrong?

```
$node = $nodeStorage->load($nid);
$paragraphs = $node->get('field_content')->referencedEntities();
// Initialize new $nested items - THIS PART WORKS.
foreach($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
  $nested = Paragraph::create(['type' => 'my_type',]);
  $nested->set('field_text', 'Some Value.');
  $nested->save();
  $paragraph->get('field_paragraphs')->appendItem($nested);
  $paragraph->save();
  $node->save();
  }
}
// Add $nested translations - THIS PART DOESN'T WORK
$languages = $node->getTranslationLanguages();
  foreach ($languages as $language) {
  $langcode = $language->getId();
  $translation = $node->getTranslation($langcode);
  $paragraphs = $translation->get('field_content')->referencedEntities();
  // Set first picture values.
  foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
    $paragraph_translation = $paragraph->getTranslation($langcode);
    $nested = $picture->get('field_paragraphs')->referencedEntities();
    $nested = reset($picture_item);
    $newValues = [
      'field_text => 'Translated value',
    ];
    $nested->addTranslation($langcode, $values);
    $nested->save();
    $picture->save();
    $translation->save();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to access the field directly instead of using the `get` method?

like this:

```php
// Add $nested translations
$languages = $node->getTranslationLanguages();
  foreach ($languages as $language) {
  $langcode = $language->getId();
  $translation = $node->getTranslation($langcode);
  $paragraphs = $translation->field_content->referencedEntities();
  // Set first picture values.
  foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
    $paragraph_translation = $paragraph->getTranslation($langcode);
    $nested = $picture->field_paragraphs->referencedEntities();
    $nested = reset($picture_item);
    $newValues = [
      'field_text' => 'Translated value',
    ];
    $nested->addTranslation($langcode, $values);
    $nested->save();
    $picture->save();
    $translation->save();
  }
}
```